# Have sed search repeatedly from the beginning of the pattern space

Tags: sed, replace, text-processing

When you issue 's//g' commands in sed, the search is resumed, after every replacement, from right past the replaced patter. For example:

```
$ sed 's/foo/oog/g;'
ffoo
foog
```

while, if the command was applied again to the whole line, we would get `oogg` as the result (two replacements). Of course, one can just issue the same command twice, or three times - but what if I want it to run repeatedly until there are no matches? Can sed do this, or will I need to resort to awk?

Comment: You might consider restricting the context, say, with a word boundary, `'s/foo\b/oog/g;'` (matches `foo` at the end of a word).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `sed` supports branching commands like `b` and `t`

```
$ echo 'ffoo' | sed ':a s/foo/oog/; ta'
oogg
```

- `:a` marks the substitute command with label `a`
- `ta` will jump to label `a` as long as the substitution succeeds

Here's another example:

```
$ echo 'coffining' | sed ':d s/fin//; td'
cog
```

See [sed manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Programming-Commands) for full details.

Comment: curious where is usage like `:label s///` documented. i've never seen this before.

Comment: @pynexj `:label` can be used to mark any command, not just `s` command. It is similar to using labels in programming languages for use in `goto label` and other such constructs.

Comment: in the sed manual, `:label` is also described as a *command*, just like other commands. so wondering if `:label s///` usage is officially/widely supported.

Comment: perhaps `:label` can be used to mark another `:label` too? anyway, `:label s///` should work in any `sed` as far as I know, it is part of POSIX specification

Comment: just took a look at posix spec but did not find it. could you quote the related part?

Comment: search for label in https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html ... seems like `:` is the command..